# OALAction* action in actions_ with message "Unused variable 'action'"

Tags: xcode, variables, warnings

in my app all OK, but the warning "Unused variable 'action'" for line:

```
OALAction* action in actions_ with message
```

All make with Cocos2D 3.0, what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

that warning is pretty annoying so this is the solution:

```
OALAction* action __unused
```

Hope it helps!